# GetLastError for [ARB/]WGL Errors

Tags: opengl, getlasterror, wgl

It seems that certain API-specific calls set the error returned by `GetLastError()`.  For example, `wglCreateContextAttribsARB(...)` can return (information from the [specification](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/wgl_create_context.txt)):

```
ERROR_INVALID_VERSION_ARB == 0x2095
ERROR_INVALID_PROFILE_ARB == 0x2096
```

When debugging, however, I get different results.  For example, trying to use `wglCreateContextAttribsARB(...)` to set up a GL 4.5 context (which my GPU doesn't support) results in an error value of `0xC0072095`.  The lower 16 bits match the invalid version error (which makes sense because it *is* a version issue), but the upper 16 bits don't make sense to me.

I skimmed the GetLastError documentation, which said that bit 29 *should* be set for application error codes.  However, I couldn't find any justification as to why the other bits would be set, and in any case this conflicts with the ARB specification saying that such-and-such a value is returned.

What's going on?

Comment: That might actually be a bug in the GL driver. I have seen such error codes myself. It looks like the driver sets the error code to a [HRESULT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb446131.aspx), where the high bits have some specific meaning, instead of a simple windows error code, as it should.

Comment: The `GetLastError()` documentation says that "the error codes... can vary by operating system or device driver."

Comment: Modern GL enums are only 16-bit. I do not think it necessarily conflicts with anything, you just kind of assumed that the missing high 16-bits from the enumerated constant were 0.